# How to display 2-digits data using two 7447 decoder?

Tags: digital-logic, 7segmentdisplay, decoder

I have designed a circuit to display the 2-digits data using two 7447 decoder. The design is shown below.
[image]

I have two outputs, O1 and O2. O1 represents the ones digit while O2 represents the tenths digit. However, when I simulate the waveform, it is not correct partially. For example, '63', the '6' seems like is not a correct output. O1 has no issue, but O2 always has problems. How to solve this?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know anything about your simulator, but you are aware that the 7447 is open collector and is active-low?

Comment: I know 7447 is active-low decoder, that's why output 0 will light up the respective segment.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure, because I've no idea how your simulator works with such devices. Your connection looks right on first glance. So I suspected the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

You should have Y6 connected to C on the lower 7447. Otherwise the maximum you can display is 39 base ten.